# Why rational numbers in stopping times for continuous time processes

Tags: rational-numbers, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t)_{\ge 0},P)$ be a filtered probability space. Let $X_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous stochastic process adapted to $\mathcal{F}_t$. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. For instance $\tau$ is defined as

$$
\tau = \mathrm{inf}\{t\ge 0, X_t \in A \}.
$$

Then, for showing that $\tau$ is a stopping time,

$$
\{\tau \le t\}= \cup_{s\in [0,t]\cap Q}\{X_s \in A\}
$$

is considered. I am quite confused why the union is taken only over rational numbers? Some books say that it is due to continuity. What does it mean exactly? Does it mean the events $\{X_s \in A\}$ are not measurable over for some $s$ that are irrational numbers?

P.S.: I am from engineering background, just started reading on stochastic processes. It would be great if someone kindly clarify this.

Comment: Restricting the union on the RHS to the rationals ensures the union is measurable, by countable union. Any other countable family dense in $[0,t]$ would do. Note that the continuity of $X$ does not ensure by itself that $[\tau\leqslant t]$ equals the RHS for every $A$.

Comment: Well thank you. I seem to get it now. I am just repeating one of the questions asked above again: Does it mean the events $\{X_s \in A\}$ are not measurable over some $s\in [0,t]$ that are irrational numbers?

Comment: And this question makes little sense since there are lots of ways to write this set as a union of events, those unions that are over countably many events prove that this set is measurable and those that are not do not prove anything.